# Django DB design - Book specific unique URLs with unique_together

Tags: django, database-design, unique-constraint, slug, unique-index

I have two models with one to many relationship.

- A `Book` has many `Chapter`s. Both the models have a `slug` field.
- For `Book` the `slug` column is `UNIQUE`.
- For `Chapter` the `book_id` and `slug` are `UNIQUE` together.
- The `Chapter` model also has a field `order`. And `book_id` and `order` are `UNIQUE` together.

This way, I can generate unique URLs for books automatically and allow duplicate slugs for different books.

Current **`models.py`**:

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    # other fields
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=80)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.slug = unique_slug(self.title)  
        return super(Book, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Chapter(models.Model):
    #other fields
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chapters')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=80)
    order = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['book_id', 'order'], name='unique_order'),
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['book_id', 'slug'], name='unique_slug')]
        ordering = ['order']
```

books app's **`urls.py`**:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    # Book
    path('', views.BookList.as_view(), name='book-list'),
    path('create/', views.BookCreate.as_view(), name='book-create'),
    path('<slug:book_slug>/', views.BookDetail.as_view(), name='book-detail'),
    path('<slug:book_slug>/edit/', views.BookEdit.as_view(), name='book-edit'),

    # Chapter
    path('<slug:book_slug>/chapter/', views.BookDetail.as_view(), name='chapter-list'),    
    path('<slug:book_slug>/chapter/create/', views.ChapterCreate.as_view(), name='chapter-create'),
    path('<slug:book_slug>/chapter/<slug:chapter_slug>/', views.ChapterDetail.as_view(), name='chapter-detail'),
    path('<slug:book_slug>/chapter/<slug:chapter_slug>/edit/', views.ChapterEdit.as_view(), name='chapter-edit')
]
```

The downside here is, in my `chapter` views I have to query the book first and get the chapter `slug` with the matching `book_id`. While previously with just the chapter `slug` UNIQUE, I was just querying the chapter table alone.

---

My goal is to have URLs like this

1. `book/rndmstrng-alice-in-the-wonderland/chapter/down-the-rabbit-hole`
2. `book/rndmstrng-some-other-book/chapter/down-the-rabbit-hole`

---

Is there any issue in this design? Are too many `UNIQUE` constraints bad? Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: You can get both chapter and book in a single query with your current model design. Can you share your view and urls?

Comment: @IainShelvington, I have added the urls.py. This is my view - https://dpaste.org/zQbQ/slim. I think I get your point now. In my `ChapterEdit` view instead of using the chapter's slug, you want me to use the book's slug and use `select_related` - so it will be a single query. Right? Or I can just change the Model to Book, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `get_object` to query using both slugs and use `select_related` to get both objects in a single query

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    return get_object_or_404(Chapter.objects.filter(
        book__slug=self.kwargs['book_slug'],
        slug=self.kwargs['chapter_slug']
    ).select_related('book'))
```

Your table design looks fine, there are a couple of slight improvements that can be made

A `SlugField` defaults to `db_index=True`, because usually a slug field is queried against, a `UniqueConstraint` will also create an index on the fields that are passed to it. This means that you have two indexes that include your slug field, you can reduce this to one by removing the index on the field and by changing the order of the `UniqueConstraint` so that the slug field is first (the order of the fields in an index matters, you generally want the fields that are "more unique" or will be queried against without the other fields first)

```
class Chapter(models.Model):
    # Other fields
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=80, db_index=False)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            # Other constraints
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['slug', 'book'], name='unique_slug')
        ]
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please expand the answer on if this is a good design in a database context and if there are any other better implementations for the same goal?

Comment: @Ken your design looks good. Just one small suggestion that should reduce the number of indexes